# Wordpress site displaying as mobile on desktop browser

Tags: php, wordpress

My website is suddenly displaying as a mobile site when viewed on Microsoft Edge on the desktop. It's using wordpress 5.0 and It displays fine on Chrome.

The link is here https://flowersforeveryone.co.za/product-category/tulips/

the version of Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: which IE version? some additional information would be helpful

Comment: It's actually Edge... the version is Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0. I've updated the question with a link. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any extensions for your browser or other tools that allow you view pages in rendered mobile or tablet views?  ie. "Responsive Web Design Tester"

If so, try deactivating those and doing a hard refresh of your browser (clear cache).

Answer (score -1):

One possible cause could be you zoomed in accidentally in your Browser...

Did you try on Firefox or Chrome ?

Plz provide a link if you need help.

Comment: It seems to be fine in Chrome, I can't check firefox as it won't load for some reason.  I have updated the question with a link. Thank you!

Comment: In here everything's working great. I could open the link in Firefox and IE edge 42.17 displays desktop design.

Comment: Sorry @Michelle, not using VPN but you should check in display or cache settings if their are those options ?? If not you should ask you VPN provider or post a new question more specific. Now you know where the problem comes from...